# How to assign values to class instance attributes in a loop

Tags: python, class, loops, oop

```
class User:
    num_of_user = 0
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        User.num_of_user += 1

user_1 = User('A')
user_2 = User('B')
....

class Value(User):
    def __init__(self,name,value):
        User.__init__(self, name)
        self.value = value

# --> user_1.value = read a new manual input
# --> user_2.value = read a new manual input
....
```

I am not familiar with how to present instances/attributes correctly in Class.

How to write above comment in a For loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add all created User_X instances to a List/Array (users/userList) and iterate through it.

```
# step by step
user_1 = User("A")
user_2 = User("B")
user_3 = User("C")

users = []
users.append(user_1)
users.append(user_2)
users.append(user_3)

# Better way with less instances
users = [User("A"), User("B"), User("C")]
```

Now you can add a simply iteration like:

```
for user in users:
  user.value = <SOME INPUT>
```

Comment: how to make users.append() in a loop also?

Comment: @LiDong `users = map(User, ["A", "B", "C"])`

Answer (score 2):

This will do,

```
class User:
    num_of_user = 0
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        User.num_of_user += 1

names = ['A','B','C','D']
users = []
for name in names:
    users.append(User(name))

for user in users:
   user.value = 'input from user'
```

Comment: Why do you add globals to the mix for free where they are not even needed? You made your code more complex and suggest to use a feature that should only be used when you know what you are doing, Use a normal temporal variable or just append it directly.

Comment: I agree. i use globals very carefully(thats why i already mentioned it), but what if he needs to create many variable (hundreds of variable). this is easy, if you know what you are doing.

Comment: replace the 2 lines inside the loop with `object_list.appen(User(v))` and you can now delete the `glo = globals()` and even simplify the loop to `for v in Name:` as you do not use the enumeration any more. Additionally, you should never use caps letter for variable names, you should change `Name` to `names` as it is a list of names. I will suggest an edit on your post so that you can accept it.